# The tag [site.master] really means [master-pages]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I recently noticed a 10-year-old tag [site.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site.master) that described itself as the same as [masterpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masterpage), which is a synonym of [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages). That means that, indirectly, [site.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site.master) means the same thing as [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages).

I checked its tag synonyms and some of its questions and I believe that these two tags are the same.

Am I wrong? If not, please make [site.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site.master) a synonym to [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the [6 questions in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsite.master%5D+-%5Basp.net%5D+-%5Bc%23%5D+-%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+-%22ASP.net%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that weren't related to C# or ASP.Net. I found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26789641/4099593) that might probably not be related to the same tag. Do check the post and retag if required. Apart from this everything else was related to [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages).

Given that the majority of the posts were the same, I added [site-master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-master) as a synonym to [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages):

[site.master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site.master) (× 94) → [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages) (× 2804)